# simple jquery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

I need help with jquery. Sorry for my bad english, but i think, that you can understand me.

I have got menu, where on mouse over  i must  show submenu, and when mouse out this menu i must hide. Here is link: http://butteff.ru/site/menu.htm
But i don't know how to do it with this:

1. when I hover on "quadro" - show dropdown
2. when I mouse out from quadro - it must hide
3. when I mouse out from submenu - it must hide
4. When i mouseout from "quadro" to submenu - it is might not hide

I tryed to do it ( http://butteff.ru/site/menu.htm ) but it is not work.
Where is my problem? Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

you have an error `$(".dropdown").mouseOut is not a function`

try `mouseout` instead of `mouseOut`

Comment: http://butteff.ru/site/menu2.htm I change it, but it still not works good. May be trouble into algorithm?

Comment: can you post some relevant code, particularly where you have applied `mouseout`

Answer (score 1):

In your script you have the following:

```
  $('.dropdown').mouseOut(function() {...});
```

This is wrong as there is a typo.  The mouseOut should be mouseout as shown below:

```
  $('.dropdown').mouseout(function() {...});
```

Comment: butteff.ru/site/menu2.htm I change it, but it still not works good. May be trouble into algorithm? What do yo think about it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly put the finger on the problem in your code (most probably it fails because 'mouseout' event for link fires before 'mouseover' event for the menu)

I can, however, provide you with my own solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/akoptsov/U5seb/), which uses `$.stop()` to suppress fading out on mouse movement from the link to the menu. Hope it helps.